# ngx-bootstrap tooltip displays on focus on mobile; despite triggers set to hover only

Tags: javascript, angular, tooltip, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using ngx-bootstraps tooltip functionality and the behaviour I'm looking for is to display the tooltip on hover on desktop but essentially disable it on mobile entirely. Figured if I lock it to use the hover trigger only this would solve my problem.

In the documentation it claims that the default triggers for the tool tip are `triggers="hover focus"`. As I don't want the focus to be in effect I manually set the triggers to `triggers="hover"`.

This works as expected on desktop, tooltip displays on hover; but on mobile, the tooltip still insists on displaying when tapped as if the focus trigger was still in effect.

Is there something specific I need to do to disable the default behaviour?

Template below:

```
<ng-template #tooltipTemplate>
  <div class="notification-level-tooltip tooltip-inner">
    <span class="tooltip-text">
      {{details | translate}}
    </span>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<span class="notification-level label" [ngClass]="labelClass" [tooltip]="tooltipTemplate" triggers="hover">
  {{text | translate}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put these classes `notification-level-tooltip tooltip-inner` in css media queries specifying the `min` and `max` screen sizes, in your case desktop. These queries will then take care of what will be shown in what screen size. [How @media queries work](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_media_queries_demystified_min-width_and_max-width/)